# How to find stores, bars, internet cafes etc.. in GTA-4

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-iv

Is there anyway to quickly find where the stores, bars, internet cafes, food joints etc.. in GTA4 (PC version) other than walking up and down the streets looking for buildings to enter or having the place introduced in a mission?

Thanks

Comment: I would have said look at your map and minimap but I assume you looked there before asking so no idea where you can see it then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The game comes with a poster-sized map which shows most of those locations:

[image]

There are also plenty of [interactive maps](http://www.gta4.net/map/) on the web.

I would also assume that you could get a mod for the PC version which would make the in-game map more detailed.

Otherwise I think you're just supposed to learn your way around the city!

Comment: I purchased the game via Steam so no map for me. IMHO they should make the businesses you can go into a little more noticeable.